# Detect full word match only from dictionary

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta

I'm trying to detect city names from dictionaries But if there is any word without spaces it's also get detected.
For example:

**Dictionary Start**

New York
..

**Dictionary End**

**Input Start**

New York

NewYork

**Input End**

What i want to anotate **New York** as City not **NewYork**

I'm using below rule.

```
WORDLIST USCitiesList = 'en/ruta/dictionaries/USCities.txt';
DocumentAnnotation{-> MARKFAST(USCity, USCitiesList,true)};
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]The below script will help you.

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
DECLARE USCity;
DECLARE NoSpaceUSCity;
WORDLIST USCitiesList = 'USCities.txt';

DocumentAnnotation{-> MARKFAST(USCity, USCitiesList,true)};

RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
DocumentAnnotation{-> MARKFAST(NoSpaceUSCity, USCitiesList,true)};
RETAINTYPE;

USCity{PARTOF(NoSpaceUSCity)->UNMARK(USCity)};
```

Comment: Gaurav actually it's working for me. I've used your sample input.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working now there was an entry 'YORK' in dictionaries that's why I was facing issue.

Comment: This script is not working for below use case( Kapolei is a city as well as nospace usaCity ) so this will not detected as City.

Answer (score 1):

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
DECLARE USCity;
DECLARE NoSpaceUSCity;
WORDLIST USCitiesList = 'USCities.txt';

DocumentAnnotation{-> MARKFAST(USCity, USCitiesList,true)};



RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
CW CW+{-> MARKFAST(NoSpaceUSCity, USCitiesList,true)};
RETAINTYPE;

USCity{PARTOF(NoSpaceUSCity)->UNMARK(USCity)};
```

Comment: If you have any issues let me know

Comment: I want to annotate: New York , California as USCity.

Input given is: New York , NewYork, California

Dictionary contains: New York , California

But using above case , i am not able to annotate California as USCity.

Comment: Either all whitespaces are considered or none in the dictionary lookup. If you ned to check on the whitespces, you need to use the rules of the answer and add all entires of permutations of allowed whitespaces to the dictionary. However, I rather recommend some cascaded approach where you postprocess the output of the dictionary lookup, e.g., with maybe two dictionaries, one whitespace insensitive and one with exceptions.